How to merge cells for `row_type` = label with other columns when `label` is very long
The primary goal of this question is to produce reproducible tables using an R script without manual changes after exporting the table to a specific format. Also, for readability I want to include the full site name (including some additional information) that is difficult to abbreviate into a smaller segment.
I have a table containing multiple statistics per group (in this case the group are sites). I have a couple of sites that have a really long name that forces the first column to expand to contain all the characters. This makes the table larger than necessary.
Hence, for the rows with the 'row_type` = label I want all the cells in the columns after the label to be merged into one cell. I think this will prevent the first column to expand in such way that it has a lot of white space.
Below is an example with a really long name (I left the HTML output out of the results as I am not sure if HTML is supported).
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)


example_data <- tibble(species = c(replicate(10, "species_1"),
                                   replicate(10, "species_2"),
                                   replicate(10, "species_3")),
                       site_1 = rnorm(30),
                       site_2_realy_long_name_that_goes_on_and_on = rnorm(30),
                       site_3 = rnorm(30)) %>% 
  mutate(species = factor(species, levels = c("species_1", "species_2", "species_3")))

table_1 <- example_data %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    include = starts_with("site"),
    by = species, # split table by group
    missing = "no", # don't list missing data separately
    type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ c("{N_miss}",
                                          "{mean} ({sd})",
                                          "{median} ({p25}, {p75})",
                                          "{min}, {max}")
    )
  )

table_1$table_body |>
  dplyr::filter(row_type == "label")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#>   variable                var_type var_label row_type label stat_1 stat_2 stat_3
#>   <chr>                   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 site_1                  continu… site_1    label    site… <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 2 site_2_realy_long_name… continu… site_2_r… label    site… <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 3 site_3                  continu… site_3    label    site… <NA>   <NA>   <NA>

Created on 2024-08-07 with reprex v2.1.1
I have tried to transform the table_1 to a gt object (table_1 |> as_gt()) and see if I can modify it from there. I have found functions to merge columns, but this will affect all rows. Other questions on stackoverflow deal with merging rows in a single column.
The desired output is a merged label rows with the label column and the stat_xx columns that contains the label.
Current output (markdown doesn't support indenting with spaces):
| label                                      | stat_1 | stat_2 | stat_3 |
| ------------------------------------------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| site_1                                     |        |        |        |
|     Stat 1..x                              |   1    |   1    |   1    |
| site_2_realy_long_name_that_goes_on_and_on |        |        |        |
|     Stat 2..x                              |   2    |   2    |   2    |
| site_3                                     |        |        |        |
|     Stat 3..x                              |   3    |   3    |   3    |

Desired output (unfortunately markdown does not support cell merging):
| label           | stat_1 | stat_2 | stat_3 |
| --------------- | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| site_1                                     |
|     Stat 1..x   |   1    |   1    |   1    |
| site_2_realy_long_name_that_goes_on_and_on |
|     Stat 2..x   |   2    |   2    |   2    |
| site_3                                     |
|     Stat 3..x   |   3    |   3    |   3    |

As noted in the intro, the goal is to make reproducible tables using a R script. As such, I am looking for a programmatic solution that does not require manual changes of some exported output.

Can you share a sample of your desired output?

Example added. It is complicated to add the example as markdown by default does not support merging of cells. Hope this helps.

Not possible just to shorten the site 2 name or do the column resizing in an editor after the table is produced in R? Imagine not/doesn't fit your needs but just thought I'd ask the dumb q.

Sure, that is a possibility. But it kind of defeats the purpose of creating reproducible tables using an R script. I can easily fix my problem by editing the output exported to Word or  Excel or HTML. Since the reproducible part without manual intervention is important, I will add it to the original question.
